# ionic app blocked by CORS policy, jsonp not working neither

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cors

I'm developing a Ionic app with angular 5, I run it in localhost with the command `ionic serve -l`

I have a get call to an external web https://example.com/api?req1=foo&req2=bar

But I get the CORS denied message and no response.

> Failed to load https://example.com/api?req1=foo&req2=bar: Redirect from 'https://example.com/api?req1=foo&req2=bar' to 'http://example.com/api?req1=foo&req2=bar' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.

The request code is simple:

```
getSomethingList(req1: number, req2: number): Observable<Item[]> {
    const requestUrl = 'https://example.com/api?req1=foo&req2=bar';
    return this._http.get(requestUrl).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

I tried to install chrome extension `Moesif Origin & CORS changer` I activated it and seated the origin at `http://localhost:8100/` (where is running my ionic app). Still with no results, but now I don't see the denied CORS error, I see no error at all.

I tried a proxy:

```
// file ionic.config.json
{
  "name": "movielovers",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [{
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "https://example.com/api"
   }]
}
```

and then changed `const requestUrl = 'https://example.com/api?req1=foo&req2=bar'` to `const requestUrl = '/api?req1=foo&req2=bar'`, I still don't know what I'm doing with this, for me it has no sense, but it is what I understood reading some tutorials.

This way obviously, I get the error:

> GET http://localhost:8100/api?req1=foo&req2=bar 404 (Not Found)

I tried to install nom corsproxy: `npm install -g corsproxy` and run corsproxy in the command line. This begins the server in a port. But this isn't working. I tried even to mix the corsproxy with the proxy in ionic.config.json file, but no way. Never get an answer.

and at last I tried with jsonp:

- first I `import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';` in app.module.ts and I declare the JsonpModule in the imports.
- then in the provider where I have the request I inject the Jsonp library `constructor(private jsonp: Jsonp) {}`
- I add a callback at the end of the request url: `const requestUrl = 'https://example.com/api?req1=foo&req2=bar&callback=JSONP_CALLBACK'`
- change the request method: 
  return this.jsonp.request(requestUrl).map((res: Response) => res.json());

And with the jsonp the error in console is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

I don't know what else try, I can't get any response because of the CORS. The api I'm requesting is not restricted, as is responding to postman, and even to write the request url directly in the browser. But when running from localhost it is obviously blocked, and I can't get over it and I'm loosing a lot of time trying to get a response. I need some help.

- ionic: 3.20.0
- Cordova
- Angular CLI: 1.7.3
- Node: 8.9.4

FYI: the api I'm using is https://www.comicvine.com/api

**edit:**
installed cordova-plugin-whitelist

added `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">` to www/index.html

the file config.xml has the lines:

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved it, first I returned all my code to the initial point (deleting all the proxies references, jsonp, etc..) where I got the CORS denial answer. Then I deleted the chrome extension `Moesif Origin & CORS changer` and installed the chrome extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi), turn it on and now it's working fine.

Maybe it helps somebody in the future, and saves him/her a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

CORS has to be handled properly at **server-side**. When you not owning the server-side you can only setup a proxy for CORS that handle the requests from your app properly and redirect them to the api (a simple php script would do the trick) but there are many ready to use solutions [out there](https://gist.github.com/jimmywarting/ac1be6ea0297c16c477e17f8fbe51347)

You can't disable CORS. It's a security "feature" from the underlying webview.

For your concrete problem with npm corsproxy try

1. Don't use the ionic proxy settings.
2. run the corsproxy on commandline.
3. change your api calls to  http://localhost:1337/my.domain.com/path/to/resource where my.domain.com/.. is the server and path you are already using at comicvine

when this is not working try something from the ready to use solutions list.

Comment: Ok, I run corsproxy (runs on 1337 port), and I make the request to `http://localhost:1337/www.comicvine.com/api/characters?api_key=myapikey&format=json` but I still get the cors denied problem. `Failed to load http://comicvine.gamespot.com/api/characters?api_key=myapikey&format=json: Redirect from 'http://comicvine.gamespot.com/api/characters?api_key=myapikey&format=json' to 'https://comicvine.gamespot.com/api/characters?api_key=myapikey&format=json' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'CORS' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: and in terminal where corsproxy is running I can read: `proxy to https://www.comicvine.com/api/characters
180421/104124.918, [response], http://localhost:1337: get /api/characters {"api_key":"myapikey","format":"json"} 301 (576ms)`

Comment: I changed my api key for the word apikey, and my request has additional params as limit and offset, I tried to simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

in proxy change Config.xml file and add new configuration property:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

or if this didn't work you can install cordova then add 'cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist':

1 - add `<allow-navigation href="*" />` to config.xml

2 - add `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">`to the header of index.html

Comment: I was going to add those lines to config.xml but they were already there. I was using also cordova, so I installed `cordova-plugin-whitelist` and added both points still same CORS error. I added the changes editing the question.